# TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined ReactJS NavBar

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to call the map function, but I'm struggling to get it to work. 
Somewhere my props may be undefined, but im not sure how to fix it...

data.js

```
[{text:"name", url:"/url", submenu:[{"text":"name", "url":"/url"}]
```

Home.js

```
import { data } from './NavBar/data.js';

<NavBar items={data}/>
```

NavBar.js

```
generateItem(item) {
    return <NavItem url={item.url} text={item.text} submenu={item.submenu}/>;
}
render() {
    var items = this.props.items.map(this.generateItem);
    return (
        <ul className="menu">
            {items}
        </ul>
    );
}
```

When running, the error gives me: TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Comment: This error can be a bit confusing but it's generally thrown because the property you're trying to call ".map" on does not exist. Check if this.props.items actually exists under the name you expect and that it is an array.

Comment: If the data.js is returning the array in a static manner, it shouldn't be undefined at first moment. however, you can always manage it via
`if (!items) return null;`